# I am looking to create script in Bamboo where Build should fail if one file is not updated for master branch but pass if it's feature branch

Tags: git, shell, bamboo

I am looking to create script in Bamboo where Build should fail if one file is not updated for master branch but pass if it's feature branch.
As a developer, I want the build plans to apply the correct policy to ABC file so that my builds will fail only when they should and pass otherwise.

## !/bin/bash

date=$(stat -c %y)$1
while true
         do date2=$(stat -c %y$1)
                if (date2 != date)
                        echo "error!"
        done

Answer (score 1):

I would go with combination of Inject variables task and Conditional task plugin

In details scheme would be like this:

1. Script task with code you shared. As result it should generate prop.properties file like
   should_fail=true #$ or false otherwise. 
   It should take ${bamboo.planRepository.1.branch} name, compare it to "master" value and to date2 condition.
2. Inject variable task which takes produced by previous task prop.properties file and put them to Local variables
3. Script task with single command "exit 1". It should be conditional task which is enabled by plugin from Marketplace: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1219706/conditional-tasks-for-bamboo
   Use variable condition with variable name "inject.should_fail" with value "true"